# how to set params in the url angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using angular 2 for my application

I have a pagination ,when i go to 3rd page and refresh it again goes back to the 1st page which i don't want,for that i want to set params in the url
 so onload i get the params and set the current page

here is my code

```
fnSetPagination(iCurrrentPage) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(url+"?page="+icurrentPage);
    this.iCurrrentPage = iCurrrentPage;
    this.paginationData = {
      start: Math.ceil((this.iCurrrentPage * this.itemsPerPage - (this.itemsPerPage)) + 1),
      limit: this.itemsPerPage
    }
    this.fnGetdata();
  }
```

on click of next page fnSetPagination triggers there i should set the param,by using this.router.navigateByUrl i can see param in my url but again my ngoninit is triggering which is not suggested .what is the other way to implement

Comment: Usually the router is used for that https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html but you can also use `window.location` directly.

Comment: You can store the current page user is viewing in cookie or localstorage and on refresh you can navigate to that specific page `this.router.navigate(['/customers', { page: pageNoBeforeRefresh }]);`

Comment: Even when i try with window.location.hash and this.router.navigate([url,{page:2}] again my ngOnInit is executing which i don't want how should i prevent that ,because it is hitting my server twice

Comment: It should not navigate to other url,in the same page on triggering one function i should update my param "page".It should not load ,just should update my param